# Shared excel work book

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel

I am Using SharePoint Server 2013 in our office and I want to use one Microsoft Office Excel file as a shared work book, meaning I uploaded one excel sheet to document library in one particular site, I want to share that excel sheet to edit all users more than 900 users at a time with out any disturbance, is it possible?

We are not installed any excel web access servers in our office, with out this I tried but it is not working means only one user is editing that excel sheet is ok if second user try to open that file it is getting Read only mode, peoples are not able to edit that excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on how co-authoring works, hope this helps:
[Overview of co-authoring in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718249.aspx)

Comment: We are not using internet  Intranet Only, as per security reasons we are not supposed to connect our server to internet